# Variable at POST

Tags: php, mysql, variables

In this code you can see arraying data from MySQL database and preparing them to change.
But I have a problem with a variables `$_POST[$here]`. How do I can insert the variable to that place. Read the code for better understanding. This code does not work. Are there some other ways. Or that is impossible to do something like this thing. If I do not use variables that changing me every or no one value. I am crying right now, that is so frustrating problem. Thanks for every answer...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error())){
$link = $row['link'];
$tittle = $row['tittle'];
$content= $row['content'];
echo "<div>";
echo "<form name='"; echo $link; echo "' method='POST' action='login.php'>";
echo "<h1>"; echo $link; echo "</h1>";
echo "<h3>"; echo $tittle; echo "</h3>";
echo "<input type='text' name='"; echo $link; echo "tittle'>";
echo "<h3>"; echo $content; echo "</h3>";
echo "<textarea name='"; echo $link; echo "content'></textarea>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='"; echo $link; echo "' value='change'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
$var1 = $link."tittle"; $titt = $_POST[$var1];
$var2 = $link."content"; $ten = $_POST[$var2];
mysql_query("UPDATE inbox SET tittle='".$titt."', content='".$ten."' WHERE link='".$link."'"); 
echo $link;
}
```

I fixed that!!!

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query` anymore, used prepared statements instead.

Comment: Also **escape your input**, never never never ever trust `$_POST`.

Comment: mysql_ function have been depricated. Use PDO instead http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Finally, you define `$titt` and then use `$tit`

Comment: Assuming this is taking user input, you need an action defined for the form. Do you have some dummy data you could show to give a bit of context as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I know there are lot of small errors question was just how to insert variable into $_POST. Or some other way to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding the security errors, you can try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error())){
    $link = $row['link'];
    $tittle = $row['tittle'];
    $content= $row['content'];
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<form name='" . $link . "' method='POST'>";
    echo "<h1>" . $link . "</h1>";
    echo "<h3>" . $tittle . "</h3>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='" . $link . "tittle'>";
    echo "<h3>" . $content . "</h3>";
    echo "<textarea name='" . $link . "content'></textarea>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='" . $link . "' value='change'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";

    $var1 = $link."tittle";
    $var2 = $link."content";

    if (isset($_POST[$var1]) and isset($_POST[$var2])) {
        $titt = $_POST[$var1];
        $ten = $_POST[$var2];
        mysql_query("UPDATE inbox SET tittle='".$titt."', content='".$ten."' WHERE link='".$link."'"); 
    }

    echo $link;
}
```

Comment: I think that way of inserting variables into $_POST is not correct. PHP does not support it. I said that is so frustrating.

Comment: You are sure the form are been submitted? Try a `var_dump($_POST)` and see if you are using the right index

Comment: Yes I am sure. Because I know problem is that variables at the POST, I only search for fix.

Comment: Post what the `var_dump($_POST)` show. Will help me see what is going on.

Comment: array(3) { ["index_phptittle"]=> string(0) "" ["index_phpcontent"]=> string(0) "" ["index_php"]=> string(6) "change" } oh now we explored we must clear the $link string of the .php because that is making _php

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of wrong with your code:

1. You use `mysql_*` functions instead of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
2. You don't escape your `$_POST` value exposing your website for any hacker to hack into. At least use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but see point 1
3. You define `$titt` and then use `$tit`, which causes an error
4. You keep `echo`ing instead of simply concatenating a string and then `echo`ing that string

There's a lot to fix...

Comment: I know but there are many errors, just not fatal.. There is no problems with mysql I need only insert variable into $_POST... 
escape string is not needed right now so I write it simpliest I know write here...